# Laravel - how to display data of two tables using their pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-blade

### There are three tables:

-
`users` (`id`, `name`,`email`,`password`)

-`roles`(`id`, `name`)

-`user_roles`(`user_id`,`role_id`)

### What I am trying to do

Get the `user_id` from `user_roles` and using a `foreach` loop, display which   `role_id` are assigned from `role` to it e.g.

John Doe | Manager

Jane Doe | Admin

EDIT: In response to Andy Holmes comment below:

In `User` model, the following relationship exists, with an inverse in the `Role` model.

```
public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Comment: I haven't written a query yet (I'm balking more or less), but my strategy is to have a join statement collate the results. Is that the right way to go?

Comment: You would want to look over Laravel's relationships documentation in order to use laravel to its full potential: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I suggest you use (Many to many) relationships. Probably a better fit than join since you'll probably want to display user only once.

Comment: I was just about to say, if you're using a relationship you should be able to quickly query this

Comment: @AndyHolmes, sorry should've mentioned this before: There's the relationship in `User` model: `public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withTimestamps();
    }`

Comment: So if you do something like `dd($user->roles)` does it return anything?

Comment: @AndyHolmes, Okay you've shown me the light. I think you're suggesting that in each foreach iteration, I use `$user->roles` and output the result? Brilliant. Could you author that in an answer below please?

Comment: That's right yeah :) Have done so for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the scenario correctly, you should be able to access this directly from your `Model`'s `Relationship`.

You can do the following to access the user's role information:

`$user->roles` and place this inside your loop